# Regex (HTML input pattern) for username

Tags: regex, input

I don't quite understand how to put a regex expression together. I keep trying to combine stuff from similar threads I've seen here, with stuff I've been googling, but I seem to be doing this all wrong.

The only thing I can get right is

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{6,20}
```

But when I try to add more to the pattern, it doesn't seem to be working.

**NOTE** This is using the **HTML input pattern attribute**.
I would appreciate some assistance on this, but I would also appreciate if someone could break down the solution for me, so I could comprehend it a little better.

- Username can contain uppercase/lowercase letters
- Username can contain numbers
- Username can contain underscore, hyphen or period
- Username cannot contain spaces
- Username cannot contain special characters
- Username should be between 6-20 characters in length

I've tried something like this:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-]{6,20}\S
```

I feel like I'm sort of there, but not quite there.

Comment: You could match a word character, dot or a hyphen without the `\S` at the end `[\w.-]{6,20}`

Answer (score 2):

The following should work:

```
[A-Za-z0-9\-_\.]{6,20}
```

To break it down:

- `A-Z` *any uppercase char*
- `a-z` *any lowercase char*
- `0-9` *any number*
- `\-` *hyphen (escaped by '\' depending on what order it is put)*
- `.` *period*

The hyphen doesn't need be escaped depending on the ordering:

```
[A-Za-z0-9-_.]{6,20}
```

or

```
[A-Za-z0-9_.-]{6,20}
```

should work, while the following shouldn't:

```
[A-Za-z0-9_-.]{6,20}
```

In the pattern you were using the *`\S`* matches any character that is not whitespace so it would expect an extra character after the 6-20 char string. As no white space (*`\s`*) is within the square brackets, the omission means spaces are not allowed; this is the same for special characters.

Comment: Period doesn't need to be escaped in a character class. `[A-Za-z0-9_]` can be shortened in `\w`